# mongodb query: result with conditional find

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, kmongo

I'm trying to do an conditional find in MongoDB.
Given a collection with the following fields:

```
itemId: Long
itemName: String
unconsumed: Boolean
snooze: Boolean
expiryTs: Long
```

I want to find all items depending on whether they are `unconsumed`, depending on `snooze` the expiryTs should by conditionally evaluated, like this:

```
if (snooze)
    expiryTs < now + 1
else
    expiryTs < now + 2
```

I use KMongo to query the collection, but with the following query

```
collection.find(and(PantryDomain::unconsumed eq true,
                    expr(cond(PantryDomain::snooze eq true,
                              PantryDomain::expiryTs lt Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli(),
                              PantryDomain::expiryTs lt Instant.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli()))))
```

I get this error:

`com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 16020 and error message 'Expression $lt takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.' on server localhost:27017`

Any idea what's wrong with the query? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
collection.find(and(PantryDomain::unconsumed eq true,
                    expr(cond(PantryDomain::snooze eq true,
                              lt PantryDomain::expiryTs Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli(),
                              lt PantryDomain::expiryTs Instant.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli()))))
```

you can also simplify it as

```
collection.find(and(PantryDomain::unconsumed,
                    expr(cond(PantryDomain::snooze,
                              lt PantryDomain::expiryTs Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli(),
                              lt PantryDomain::expiryTs Instant.now().plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toEpochMilli()))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work, for once `lt` is an infix function
`infix fun <T> KProperty<T>.lt(item: T): Bson = Filters.lt(path(), item)`

simplifying also won't work, but this is not an issue